# Is it possible to change Rust benchmark results to a different time unit?

Tags: rust, benchmarking

I just ran some Rust benchmarks and I see that the results are always displayed in `ns`. Is is possible to change the time units of the benchmark to something else? For example, to `ms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Unless you want to write a wrapper script that runs a regex and replaces the numbers after dividing them, but I doubt that’s what you meant.

There are 10^9 nanoseconds in a second.

Comment: Thanks for the info. No, I was not looking to a manual solution as writing a wrapper, something more automatic.